# Is there any intuition behind the definition of a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure, intuition

It doesn't look like this question has been asked or answered. The definition of a continuous random variable that I have is:

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ on which there is a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, then
$X$ is said to be a continuous random variable if its Probability Law ($P_X$) is absolutely continuous with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

Is there any intuition that can be brought to bear on it? I realize that a definition is just that, a definition, but is there any reason why we should define a RV as continuous because $$\lambda(A) = 0 \Rightarrow P_X(A) =0, A \in \mathcal{A}$$

Comment: Some people would define "continuous random variable" differently: Just a random variable with a continuous CDF function $F_X(x)=P[X\leq x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  However the "absolutely continuous" part is an additional assumption that ensures existence of a PDF. It is possible to have a continuous CDF but no PDF.

Comment: Also I think you have stated it backwards: $X$ is absolutely continuous if for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ we have $\lambda(A)=0\implies P[X \in A]=0$.

Comment: @Michael. Thanks and agreed. I will edit.

Comment: @Michael: It would seem then that the definition I have is stronger than necessary - a RV might be continuous but $F'_X$ might not exist. Can you point me at a reference that talks about what the absolute continuity of measures is doing?

Comment: Here is a related link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298293/absolutely-continuous-random-variable-vs-continuous-random-variable

Comment: @user3716267, meaning that all the mass is distributed only over continuous sets, e.g., intervals?? Is that the hook? If so I get it ...

Comment: @Michael. Great, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you’re approaching this rather theoretically. Suppose for example that $X$ is the amount of time you have to wait until the next customer walks into your store. How would you describe how likely $X$ is to take on various values? Of course $P(X=x) =0$ for any $x \in \mathbb R$, so writing down a probability mass function will not help. So, we instead write down a probability *density* function, and we have just discovered the idea of a continuous random variable.

Comment: @littleO, yes, I think you might be right. I was hung up on the why a RV having zero measure on Lebesgue sets with zero measure "made it" continuous instead of looking at what that implied for the Probability Law itself. To all, thank you. I think I might be okay now.